# minify ajax request for same pattern of call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Hello guys just wanted to minify this code because of memory and time issue 
i just wanted to minify it because of the same pattern call by ajax

i am using ajax function to get my content in a css class
**kindly look below of my codes and it pattern**

```
        $("#poto").click(function (e) {
$("#loadimg").show(); 
jQuery.ajax({ url: "photos.php", 
         cache: true,
            success:function(response){
                $(".homefeed").html(response);
                  $("#elementcontainer").show();
                $("#loadimg").hide(); 
            },
            });return false;
    });


            $("#mkt").click(function (e) {
$("#loadimg").show(); 
jQuery.ajax({ url: "newm.php", 
         cache: true,
            success:function(response){
                $(".homefeed").html(response);
                  $("#elementcontainer").hide();
                $("#loadimg").hide(); 
            },
            });return false;
    });

        $("#invite").click(function (e) {
$("#loadimg").show(); 
jQuery.ajax({ url: "invite/index.php", 
         cache: true,
            success:function(response){
                $(".homefeed").html(response);
                $("#loadimg").hide(); 
            },
            });return false;
    });
```

...... goes on 10 times more like this

is there any way to minify it because it is taking too much time to load in a content in .homefeed class and also is is taking much bytes /

any way to how to achieve it? thanks

Comment: Declare the handler function and use a reference instead of repeating the same anonymous function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare a new function which will handle the ajax request and the success response:

```
function ajaxLoadImage(url, showElementContainer) {
    $("#loadimg").show(); 
    jQuery.ajax({ 'url': url, 
        cache: true,
        success: function(response){
            if(showElementContainer) {
                $("#elementcontainer").show();
            }
            $(".homefeed").html(response);
            $("#loadimg").hide(); 
        },
    });
    return false;
}
```

And then when you bind click event, just do:

```
$("#poto").click(function (e) { 
    ajaxLoadImage("photos.php", true);
});
```

Comment: Does it gives you an error ? I fixed a typo few minutes ago, be sure you have the latest version